# spark - set null when column not exist in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm loading many versions of JSON files to spark DataFrame.
some of the files holds columns A,B
and some A,B,C or A,C..

If I run this command

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT A,B,C FROM table")
```

after loading several I can get error "column not exist" I loaded only files that are not holding column C.
How can set this value to `null` instead of getting error?

Answer (score 2):

[`DataFrameReader.json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json) method provides optional schema argument you can use here. If your schema is complex the simplest solution is to reuse one inferred from the file which contains all the fields:

```
df_complete = spark.read.json("complete_file")
schema = df_complete.schema

df_with_missing = spark.read.json("df_with_missing", schema)
# or
# spark.read.schema(schema).("df_with_missing")
```

If you know schema but for some reason you cannot use above you have to create it from scratch.

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", LongType(), True), ..., StructField("C", LongType(), True)])
```

As always be sure to perform some quality checks after loading your data.

**Example** (note that all fields are `nullable`):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("x1", FloatType()),
    StructField("x2", StructType([
        StructField("y1", DoubleType()),
        StructField("y2", StructType([
            StructField("z1", StringType()),
            StructField("z2", StringType())
        ]))
    ])),
    StructField("x3", StringType()),
    StructField("x4", IntegerType())
])

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""{"x4": 1}"""]), schema).printSchema()
## root
##  |-- x1: float (nullable = true)
##  |-- x2: struct (nullable = true)
##  |    |-- y1: double (nullable = true)
##  |    |-- y2: struct (nullable = true)
##  |    |    |-- z1: string (nullable = true)
##  |    |    |-- z2: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- x3: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- x4: integer (nullable = true)

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""{"x4": 1}"""]), schema).first()
## Row(x1=None, x2=None, x3=None, x4=1)

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""{"x3": "foo", "x1": 1.0}"""]), schema).first()
## Row(x1=1.0, x2=None, x3='foo', x4=None)

spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(["""{"x2": {"y2": {"z2": "bar"}}}"""]), schema).first()
## Row(x1=None, x2=Row(y1=None, y2=Row(z1=None, z2='bar')), x3=None, x4=None)
```

**Important**:

This method is applicable only to JSON source and depend on the detail of implementation. Don't use it for sources like Parquet.

Comment: read.json() seems to only take 1 argument. this worked for me:
df_with_missing = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json("df_with_missing")

Comment: I am not sure this solution works. You can pretty much print the schema or show it without a problem, but when you try to do anything with those columns (like check if they are not null), then it fails complaining that the [column] is not in the schema (tested with Spark 2.0.2).

Comment: @marios How do you check this? Do you use JSON input?

Comment: @zero323 good question, I didn't realize this answer was JSON specific. I am using parquet. I wrote another question on this if you are kind enough to take a look :): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107245/spark-parquet-schema-fails-when-forcing-schema-on-read

Comment: @zero323 the trick I used so far is: `spark.createDataFrame(myNewDf.rdd, schema)`, this works but looks pretty ugly (and the .rdd doesn't seem to come for free).

Comment: @marios JIRA ticket could be a good idea. This looks like an undefined behavior. Since Spark supports schema merging (you could write an empty file, set `spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema` to `true`, and always read it with your data, but it is a really ugly hack) for Parquet, it should be possible to support passing schema with Parquet.