# Spark: Parquet DataFrame operations fail when forcing schema on read

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, schema, parquet

(Spark 2.0.2)

The problem here rises when you have parquet files with different schema and force the schema during read. Even though you can print the schema and run `show()` ok, you cannot apply any filtering logic on the missing columns.

Here are the two example schemata:

```
// assuming you are running this code in a spark REPL
import spark.implicits._

case class Foo(i: Int)
case class Bar(i: Int, j: Int)
```

So `Bar` includes all the fields of `Foo` and adds one more (`j`). In real-life this arises when you start with schema `Foo` and later decided that you needed more fields and end up with schema `Bar`.

Let's simulate the two different parquet files.

```
// assuming you are on a Mac or Linux OS
spark.createDataFrame(Foo(1)::Nil).write.parquet("/tmp/foo")
spark.createDataFrame(Bar(1,2)::Nil).write.parquet("/tmp/bar")
```

What we want here is to always read data using the more generic schema `Bar`. That is, rows written on schema `Foo` should have `j` to be null.

case 1: We read a mix of both schema

```
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/tmp/foo", "/tmp/bar").show()
+---+----+
|  i|   j|
+---+----+
|  1|   2|
|  1|null|
+---+----+


spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("/tmp/foo", "/tmp/bar").filter($"j".isNotNull).show()
+---+---+
|  i|  j|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

case 2: We only have Bar data

```
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/bar").show()
+---+---+
|  i|  j|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

case 3: We only have Foo data

```
scala> spark.read.parquet("/tmp/foo").show()
+---+
|  i|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

The problematic case is 3, where our resulting schema is of type `Foo` and not of `Bar`. Since we migrate to schema `Bar`, we want to always get schema `Bar` from our data (old and new).

The suggested solution would be to define the schema programmatically to always be `Bar`. Let's see how to do this:

```
val barSchema = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[Bar].schema
//barSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(i,IntegerType,false), StructField(j,IntegerType,false))
```

Running show() works great:

```
scala> spark.read.schema(barSchema).parquet("/tmp/foo").show()
+---+----+
|  i|   j|
+---+----+
|  1|null|
+---+----+
```

However, if you try to filter on the missing column j, things fail.

```
scala> spark.read.schema(barSchema).parquet("/tmp/foo").filter($"j".isNotNull).show()
17/09/07 18:13:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 230.0 (TID 481)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column [j] was not found in schema!
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:55)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.getColumnDescriptor(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:181)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.validateColumn(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:169)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.validateColumnFilterPredicate(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:151)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.visit(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:91)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.visit(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:58)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.Operators$NotEq.accept(Operators.java:194)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.predicate.SchemaCompatibilityValidator.validate(SchemaCompatibilityValidator.java:63)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.RowGroupFilter.visit(RowGroupFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.RowGroupFilter.visit(RowGroupFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat$FilterPredicateCompat.accept(FilterCompat.java:126)
    at org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.RowGroupFilter.filterRowGroups(RowGroupFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.scan_nextBatch$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to use the `createDataFrame` API with `RDD[Row]` and the new schema (which at least the new columns being nullable).

```
// Make the columns nullable (probably you don't need to make them all nullable)
val barSchemaNullable = org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType(
   barSchema.map(_.copy(nullable = true)).toArray)

// We create the df (but this is not what you want to use, since it still has the same issue)
val df = spark.read.schema(barSchemaNullable).parquet("/tmp/foo")

// Here is the final API that give a working DataFrame
val fixedDf = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, barSchemaNullable)

fixedDf.filter($"j".isNotNull).show()

+---+---+
|  i|  j|
+---+---+
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is due to parquet filter push down which is not correctly handled in parquet-mr versions < 1.9.0

You can check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-389 for more details.

You can either upgrade the parquet-mr version or add a new column and base the filter on the new column.

For eg.

dfNew = df.withColumn("new_j", when($"j".isNotNull, $"j").otherwise(lit(null)))
dfNew.filter($"new_j".isNotNull)

Answer (score 0):

On Spark 1.6 worked fine, schema retrieving was changed, HiveContext was used:

```
val barSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Bar].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
println(s"barSchema: $barSchema")
hiveContext.read.schema(barSchema).parquet("tmp/foo").filter($"j".isNotNull).show()
```

Result is:

```
barSchema: StructType(StructField(i,IntegerType,false), StructField(j,IntegerType,false))
+---+----+
|  i|   j|
+---+----+
|  1|null|
+---+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Maybe this is a regression for 2.0.2. In any case I found the trick listed in my answer to do the trick.